# How to create a Expression List for JPA Criteria Group By clause?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to create a JPA Criteria Query with a groupBy clause.
In my case, my groupBy clause is dynamic, so I'm trying to use this:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> groupBy(List<Expression<?>> grouping);
```

instead of the usual:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> groupBy(Expression<?>... grouping);
```

The problem is that I'm struggling to create this Expression List.
This is my code for the moment:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Foo> foo = criteria.from(Foo.class);

    Expression<String> barExp = foo.get("bar");
    Expression<String> bazExp = foo.get("baz");

    // I'd like to use a Expression List to build a dynamic group by clause with this. But something looks wrong and I don't know where...
    List<Expression<String>> groupBy = Arrays.asList(barExp, bazExp);

    // Consulta
    criteria.multiselect(barExp, bazExp);
    criteria.where(where);

    // this works:
    criteria.groupBy(barExp, bazExp);
    // but I'd like to use this, but compiler give me a type error
    //criteria.groupBy(groupBy);

    TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
    List<Tuple> result = query.getResultList();
```

So this is it.
How do I dynamically create a JPA 2 Criteria Expression List for a groupBy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here hoping for this to be useful for someone else.

After some thinking I've discovered that with:

```
List<Expression<String>>
```

the compiler was trying to use the undesired overloaded version:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> groupBy(Expression<?>... grouping);
```

instead of the version that I wanted:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> groupBy(List<Expression<?>> grouping);
```

Eclipse helped me to fix the type errors with my code to:

```
// ...

Expression<?> barExp = foo.get("bar");
Expression<?> bazExp = foo.get("baz");
List<Expression<?>> groupBy = Arrays.asList(codigoUGR, codigoGND);

// ...
criteria.groupBy(groupBy);
```

And this seems to fix the problem.
The Java wildcard syntax ("?") is a little unknown to me, but eclipse Quick Fix Suggestions came to the rescue again :)